# WebBrowser WPF Запуск локального HTML файла

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser

привет есть код

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MainView.Navigate("file:///C:/Users/Ultima/Desktop/MainView.html");

        }
```

все ок запускает файл. Но я хочу сделать относительный адрес.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)

    {
        MainView.Navigate("file:///MainView.html");

    }
```

но не получается. Как задать относительный путь

Comment: Может, для относительного пути нужно, чтобы файлы были в одной директории с запускаемой программой?

Comment: дак и так в одной папке.

Comment: Попробывал MainView.Navigate(new Uri("View/MainView.html", UriKind.Relative)); пишет относительный путь запрещен

Comment: var uri = new Uri("file:///C:/Users/Ultima/Documents/Visual%20Studio%202015/Projects/stream/stream/bin/Debug/View/MainView.html", UriKind.Absolute);
            MainView.Navigate(uri);   ТАК работает